Are there any church traditions of venerating the Ethiopian eunuch?

”And as they were going along the road they came to some water, and the eunuch said, “See, here is water! What prevents me from being baptized?” And he commanded the chariot to stop, and they both went down into the water, Philip and the eunuch, and he baptized him. And when they came up out of the water, the Spirit of the Lord carried Philip away, and the eunuch saw him no more, and went on his way rejoicing.“
‭‭Acts‬ ‭8‬:‭36‬, ‭38‬-‭39‬ ‭ESV‬‬

Is there any tradition of veneration of the Eunuch in acts 8? Is he canonized in any church?
